# How do I list hosts using Ansible 1.x API

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-api, ansible-runner, ansible-1.x

Ansible-playbook has a `--list-hosts` cli switch that just outputs the hosts affected by each play in a playbook. I am looking for a way to access to same information through the python API.

The (very) basic script I am using to test right now is

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import ansible.runner
import ansible.playbook
import ansible.inventory
from ansible import callbacks
from ansible import utils
import json

# hosts list
hosts = ["127.0.0.1"]
# set up the inventory, if no group is defined then 'all' group is used by default
example_inventory = ansible.inventory.Inventory(hosts)

pm = ansible.runner.Runner(
    module_name = 'command',
    module_args = 'uname -a',
    timeout = 5,
    inventory = example_inventory,
    subset = 'all' # name of the hosts group 
    )

out = pm.run()

print json.dumps(out, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

I just can't figure out what to add to `ansible.runner.Runner()` to make it output affected hosts and exit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but `ansible.runner.Runner` is actually one task and not playbook.
Your script is a more kind of [ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v1.9.6-1/bin/ansible) CLI and not [ansible-playbook](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v1.9.6-1/bin/ansible-playbook).
And `ansible` doesn't have any kind of `--list-hosts`, while `ansible-playbook` does.
You can see how listhosts is done [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v1.9.6-1/bin/ansible-playbook#L217).

Comment: I'm trying to use the ansible python module to get a list of hosts that would be affected by a playbook. Similar to running the playbook with the ansible-playbook command with `--list-hosts`, but I want the data in a more machine readable format (list a list or tuple).

Comment: Then you should implement exactly the same functionality as in ansible-playbook CLI (take the code you need and modify it). Unfortunately, there is no handy method ready for you to list affected hosts via some API call.